# How to customize the implode function structure in resource in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my resource I've got an object like below:

```
return [
    'something' => $this->somerelationship->implode('name',',')
];
```

Now it returns this result for me:

```
{
    something [
        "items,items,items"
    ]
}
```

But I want my implode to return a useable array in javascript not just making it 1 index of the array rather than that put each item in 1 slot of array-like below:

```
{
    something 
    [
        {items},{items},{items}"
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve that now ?

Comment: Return json_encode() your result, then parse json in javascript.

Comment: Instead of `implode()`, try and do: `$this->somerelantionship->pluck('name')->all()`. That should return an array with all the names.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson make it answer so i accep it it was ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `->implode()` (which takes an array and turn it into a string), try and do:

```
'something' => $this->somerelantionship->pluck('name')->all(),
```

The method `pluck()` returns an array with all the values from a specific key, which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can return

```
json_encode($this->somerelationship->pluck('name')->toArray());
```

Then in your javascripts just JSON.parse() it or put it in a variable in blade:

```
 var items = {!! json_decode($variable) !!}
```

Comment: If they do `json_encode()` on that result, it would be double encoded when they do `json_encode()` on the array they put this in.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You are right but if we get an array of our response and before before sending that, json_encode it to send to blade to have a neat respounse, We need to json_decode it first.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what you're doing here. First you json_encode() sub elements separately for some reason. Then you're assuming that they want to pass it to a blade template (which we don't know if they want to do or not. it might as well be an ajax response), but you're also doing `json_decode()`, turning the json string into a PHP object, which you're trying to store in a JS variable? That simply won't work.